How do you back up an entire Fedora Linux system at the file level?
Allegedly, it is possible to back up a complete Linux installation simply by copying the root directory's contents to a new partition, thus preserving all packages, system settings, user settings, etc. Examples:
https://askubuntu.com/a/7811

In simple terms, the backup command is:
sudo tar czf /backup.tar.gz \
   --exclude=/backup.tar.gz \
   --exclude=/dev \
   --exclude=/mnt \
   --exclude=/proc \
   --exclude=/sys \
   --exclude=/tmp \
   --exclude=/media \
   --exclude=/lost+found \
   /

...
To restore your files when the system goes pear-shaped, use a Live CD. Mount the bad system under /media or /mnt and then run tar xf /path/to/drive/with/backup.tar.gz -C /mnt (or /media).

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR#Backing_Up

The following is an exemplary command of how to archive your system.
tar -cvpzf backup.tar.gz --exclude=/backup.tar.gz --one-file-system /
...
Restore Your Backup
sudo tar -xvpzf /path/to/backup.tar.gz -C /media/whatever --numeric-owner

(By the way, the above guide says to navigate to / before creating the tar archive.)
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/full-system-recovery-using-tar-4175476338/

I haven't used tar for fullsystem backup, but I use rsync for that regularly, and I have restored it many times.
You need to exclude some more directories, and you also need to include a few files in /dev. Include must come before exclude.
--include=/dev/{console,null} --exclude={/dev/*,/proc/*,/sys/*,/tmp/*,/run/*,/mnt/*,/media/*,/lost+found}

You restore it from a LiveCD/other installed system, as you wrote it. Then you need to

change uuid in /etc/fstab. Run 'blkid' as root to find out the new uuid.
regenerate grub's configuration file. Usually by running 'update-grub'.
install grub in mbr.

You said you have other system on the same machine. Depending on which distro is "owning" mbr, you might need to run update-grub on that > system instead, and don't install grub in mbr.
It doesn't matter if you create the same partitions or if you make it different. Just mount all partitions where they should be in the new system before restoring the backup. At least this is true for rsync. As I haven't used tar for this I can't say for sure. You better test your backup before your disk fails.

(This post looked promising, but I got stuck at the update-grub part; it didn't seem available in Fedora.)
Right now I'm practicing restoring my system to a virtual machine. Here is my current disk layout on the system I want to backup, the bare-metal Fedora installation:
NAME                                          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
sda                                             8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk
├─sda1                                          8:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2                                          8:2    0   512M  0 part  /boot
└─sda3                                          8:3    0 464.8G  0 part
  └─luks-c4fd8f89-2a44-477b-a091-084aab208c07 253:0    0 464.7G  0 crypt
    ├─fedora--vg-root                         253:1    0    50G  0 lvm   /
    ├─fedora--vg-swap                         253:2    0     8G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    ├─fedora--vg-home                         253:3    0 398.8G  0 lvm   /home
    └─fedora--vg-Padding                      253:4    0     8G  0 lvm

This is an UEFI machine.
What I am trying to do is back up my system with tar, then extract that tarball within a virtual machine and recover my system, with all installed packages, system configuration (e.g., modified /etc files), and user settings in place. I have two tarballs that I tried, one without /boot, and one with /boot. Here is a view of the / directory of my tarballs:
/.config
**/afs/**
**/boot/**
**/dev/**
/etc/
**/home/**
**/lost+found/**
**/media/**
**/mnt/**
/opt/
**/proc/**
/root/
**/run/**
**/srv/**
**/tmp/**
/usr/
/var/
/.hcwd
/bin          # Symlink to usr/bin
/lib          # Symlink to usr/lib
/lib64        # Symlink to usr/lib64
/sbin         # Symlink to usr/sbin

The directories with asterisks have no data. /home is empty because I already know how to restore /home, and because the resultant tarball would be enormous with /home included.
I created this tar file by

Booting into a live OS (Fedora KDE Live x86-64, specifically)
Decrypting the LUKS partition and activating the volume group.
Mounting the installation's root partition (fedora--vg-root) at /mnt/linux.
Mounting the installation's /boot, /boot/efi, and /home partitions at the /mnt/linux/boot, /mnt/linux/boot/efi, and /mnt/linux/home respectively.
chrooting into the installation.
Using tar -cvpf ./home/$USER/Downloads/system-backup.tar.gz --one-file-system / at the root (/) directory.

Then I tried restoring the OS within a virtual machine, in multiple ways: by extracting the tar archive on top of a fresh installation, both with and without /boot; and by simply paritioning and mounting the VM disk and extracting the tar archive hoping that everything will fall into place and work. (In most cases, grub didn't find the kernel, but when I restored over a fresh installation and left /boot, /boot/efi, and /etc/fstab intact, I could decrypt the LUKS partition, but then my system hung forever trying to load the rest of the OS.)
I've been trying for at least a week, and I can't figure out what is wrong. I take it something went awry in my grub configuration or fstab, but I don't know what.

For your grub issue, see What is the equivalent of 'update-grub' for RHEL, Fedora, and CentOS systems?. And where is your /lib directory? It might be a symlink pointing to /lib64 on your installed system, do you have that symlink in the new system so that your copied lib64 will be picked up as the target?

＠terdon Thanks for the link. My /lib directory is a symlink to /usr/bin.

I hope that's a typo and you mean /usr/lib, right?

@terdon Ah, yes, that was an error. $ ls -l /lib outputted lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 7  1月 23 19:00 /lib -> usr/lib

I'd use .img instead of tar, with partclone.It's on the repository. Change ext4 to match your file system type.
partclone.ext4

Create a disk image:
partclone.ext4 -c -d -s /dev/sda1 -o ~/sda1.img

Restore the image using:
partclone.ext4 -r -d -s ~/sda1.img -o /dev/sda1

The .img is the most portable and simple way to backup the entire partition.
